# dereferencing Pointer to incomplete type struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When I try to compile, i get an Error saying :" dereferencing Pointer to incomplete type struct Freunde"

Thats my struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *Name;
    struct Freunde *next;
} Freunde;
```

The Error happens here:

```
while (strcmp(Anfang->next->Name, Name) != 0)
    Anfang = Anfang->next;
```

Edit/// So here is some more Code from the Programm I do try to run:

```
void add(Freunde* Anfang, char* Name) {
    Freunde * naechster;

    while (Anfang->next != NULL) {
        Anfang = Anfang->next;
    }
    Anfang->next = (Freunde*) malloc(sizeof(Freunde));
    naechster = Anfang->next;
    naechster->Name = Name;
    naechster->next = NULL;

}


int main() {
    Freunde *liste;
    liste = (Freunde*) malloc(sizeof(Freunde));

    liste->Name = "Mert";
    liste->next = NULL;    

    add(liste, "Thomas");
    add(liste, "Markus");
    add(liste, "Hanko");

    Ausgabe(liste);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct{` --> `typedef struct Freunde {`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I didn't see `struct Freunde *next;` because I saw `Anfang->next->Name` why would someone code like that.

Comment: @iharob `Freunde` and `*next` are  different type.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes I understand now.

Comment: You don't need to cast `malloc()` return value to `(Freunde *)`.

Comment: Why not? Sorry, im very new to programming

Comment: @Scarh perhaps ask yourself why *would* you cast it.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that you defined the `next` member of your structure as `struct Freunde *next;` but there is no `struct Freunde` in your code.

First declare a `struct Freunde`, like this

```
struct Freunde
{
    char *name;
    struct Freunde *next;
};
```

and then you could `typedef`, but you don't have to

```
typedef struct Freunde Freunde;
```

Also:

1. Do not cast the return value of `malloc()` for [these reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495)
2. Always check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you man,  it worked out. But why do I write "Freunde" twice and not typedef struct Freunde;

Comment: Thanks alot !  (just fillin up to 15 characters)

Comment: @Scarh `typedef` introduces an alias for an existing type. You are adding the alias `Fruende` for the type `struct Fruende`.    Your suggestion would have no effect (it's syntactically valid, by accident, but it doesn't introduce any new aliases).

Answer (score 0):

Another aspect of the problem, or another way to think about it, is you are creating a `typedef` from a struct and attempting to include a pointer to that struct type as a member.

```
typedef struct {
    char *Name;
    struct Freunde *next;
} Freunde;
```

As explained, when you declare the member pointer `struct Freunde *next;`, the compiler has no idea what `Freunde` is yet. Thus the error.

To remedy this, you can either do as described in the other answer, or include a struct name tag in your declaration.

```
typedef struct Freunde {
    char *Name;
    struct Freunde *next;
} Freunde;
```

In this case `struct Freunde {...` tells the compiler that there is a struct named `Freunde`, so when it reaches your member `struct Freunde *next;` it is fine.

Comment: `Freunde` is different from `struct Freunde`. Also, `struct {...} Freunde;` without the `typedef` declares a **variable**.

Comment: Thank you, I liked that method more than just typing                         typedef struct Freunde Freunde;  after my struct.